# subset and change multiple columns with different "functions"

Tags: python, pandas

How is it possible to change multiple columns on subset by some conditions in a pandas dataframe?

For example given the input data:

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({"y": ("441912", "abc", "121", "4455")})
dat['leny'] = dat['y'].str.len()
dat['yfoo'] = None

dat

        y leny yfoo
1: 441912    6   NA
2:    abc    3   NA
3:    121    3   NA
4:   4455    4   NA
```

Then subset the rows for which `y` starts with 44 and has a length of 4 or 5, then for those rows strip the 44 from the beginning in `y`, substract 2 from `leny` and set `yfoo` to False, resulting to the following output:

```
        y leny  yfoo
1: 441912    6    NA
2:    abc    3    NA
3:    121    3    NA
4:     55    2 FALSE
```

My attempt at doing this:

```
# pandas struggle follows
dat[dat.leny.isin((4, 5)) & dat.y.str.match('^44', na=False)]
```

What do I do next?

Comment: Can you please explain what it is you're trying to do _before_ pasting code?

Comment: oh boy, i thought it was pretty obvious in the "change multiple colums on a subset based on some conditions".... but anyway, how about now? :)

Comment: Yes, it's fine now. All you really needed was expected output. The R MCVE was redundant since most of us pandas users don't know R.

Comment: ok :) guess the -2 will remain forever :(

Answer (score 1):

Create a mask:

```
m = dat.leny.isin((4, 5)) & dat.y.str.startswith('44')
```

Now, use `loc` and perform your operations.

```
dat.loc[m, 'y'] = dat.loc[m, 'y'].str[2:]
dat.loc[m, 'leny'] -= 2
dat.loc[m, 'yfoo'] = False

dat

        y  leny   yfoo
0  441912     6   None
1     abc     3   None
2     121     3   None
3      55     2  False
```

Comment: but this will subset three times... one for each assignment, actually four times since there is also a right hand expression

Comment: @JohnSmith No way around that with pandas, unfortunately.

Comment: really? that's a pity :(

Answer (score 1):

Using a comprehension to gather data.

```
y = dat.y.values.tolist()

dat2 = np.array([
    [x[2:], len(x) - 2, False, i]
    for i, x in enumerate(y)
    if x.startswith('44') and (len(x) // 2 == 2)
], object)

dat.iloc[dat2[:, -1].astype(int), :] = dat2[:, :-1]

dat

        y  leny   yfoo
0  441912     6   None
1     abc     3   None
2     121     3   None
3      55     2  False
```

Comment: thanks, interesting..., although i see that this creates a copy of the subset which might not be very memory efficient... will need to read in a bit more detail the rest to see what's happening.

Comment: It doesn’t. It creates a “copy” of s subset